# PHP IP Address comparison strangely fails

Tags: php

I feel a little ridiculous asking this, because I believe the answer is on front of my nose, but I just can't figure out what's happening here. 
I have this code:

```
 <?php $IPAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    if ($IPAddress != '200.222.222.110' || $IPAddress != '200.222.212.111')
                {
                    var_dump($IPAddress);
                    echo 'Not the ip address';
                }
    else
                {
                   echo 'Okay, we have the IP Address';
                }
?>
```

I'm with the '200.222.222.110', and the PHP gets that. But for some reason, the if fails miserably and always get on the first statement, showing me a var_dump with this:

```
string(15) "200.222.222.110"
```

Why the PHP doesn't recognize the $IPAddress as that value and execute the else statement?

Comment: It doesn't fail because: 200.222.222.110 != 200.222.222.111 ...  I think you want to use && here...

Comment: the condition fails,
since in the condition is using an OR operator
your given IP is 200.222.222.110 and check it if not equal to 200.222.222.110 this would give you a true, since its not equal,
but when it checks again to the other statement 200.222.212.111 it would give you false, like 1+0=1 so meaning true,

use the AND operator &&, hope you understand what i mean

Comment: Neatened it up for you: http://3v4l.org/Yu5O6. Also always use strict comparison: `!==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't fail... the boolean condition is true if your IP is 200.222.222.110.

The boolean condition says that if the ip is 200.222.222.110 **or** 200.222.222.111 is true!

Comment: (s)he tests if it is different here, not equal. But the `or` issue is the same indeed.